# Migrating from Bitbucket Server to Azure DevOps

Tags: azure-devops, migration, bitbucket, bitbucket-server

While importing from Bitbucket Server which is accessible over VPN to Azure DevOps, I am facing the issue as "Clone URL is incorrect. Clone URL requires authorization". May I know how to fix this issue.

And I saw import repository option in Azure DevOps. But is there any way to import multiple projects and their repositories of Bitbucket Server to Azure DevOps?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a suggestion ticket about [add support for Bitbucket Server for Azure DevOps](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/please-please-please-add-support-for-bitbucket-ser/869760). You can vote this ticket.

As a workaround, you can use git commands to clone and push your repositories.

1.Clone the source repo to a temporary folder on your computer using the bare option.

```
git clone --bare https://github.com/contoso/old-contoso-repo.git

cd old-contoso-repo.git
```

2.Create a target repo.

3.Copy the source repo to the target repo.

```
git push --mirror https://dev.azure.com/contoso-ltd/MyFirstProject/_git/new-contoso-repo
```

Please find more detailed information in [this document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/git/import-git-repository?view=azure-devops#manually-import-a-repo).

Comment: Walter, are you saying currently importing from TFS Server and Bitbucket server is not supported in Azure DevOps?

Answer (score 1):

In Azure DevOps Import will happen from source repository URL's which are reachable from Azure DevOps Services which are basically running on cloud and require HTTPS reachability.

If BitBucket Server is hosting Repository on Private Network , it will not be reachable from Azure DevOps and hence we need the method provided by Walter above.